# Dynamically assigned class "is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript

Creating a class from a dynamic variable. "c1 is not a constructor" error.

```
var classes = [PathCarver, SolarSmasher, CoreCrusher, SunSlicer, VortexWaster];
var c1 = classes[Math.random() % classes.length - 1];
        this.p1 = new c1({'r' : 0, 'battlefield' : this, 'arsenalIndex' : 0});
```

How do I run this code as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.random() % classes.length - 1` expression does not return an integer, but a floating point number. Even more, it's never an integer, since you're applying a `%` operator to a value in the `[0; 1)` range which ends up the value in the`[0; 1)` range which you substract `1` from, so it becomes negative.

So `c1` is `undefined`.

If you want to pick a random element use `Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)` instead to generate a random valid index.

Comment: I tried that. I've had this issue even without random -- just assigning class definitions to variable then instantiating them. Please try it for yourself.

Comment: @quantumpotato it works without problems https://jsfiddle.net/armhoeL7/. Please, try it **YOURSELF**. Thanks for a downvote.

Comment: I did not downvote you. Perhaps I errored in my implementation. I will try again.

Comment: I mistyped % instead of *. Thanks for your help all!